# Decrypting .toc file

Tags: decompilation, file-format

So I have a few files from a game on my pc, most of which are `.toc` files

I believe this means they are a "table of contents" as the ending suggests, but my attempts to read them have been unsuccessful.

The contents of the files aren't inherently human-readable, and I haven't been able to really "read" them, as I am not very good at this sort of thing.

[`weapons.toc`](https://ufile.io/okaqi492) - one of the files in the game

This game uses a "developmental" Frostbite engine, I dunno how that could affect the game itself / its encryption of these files.

I am curious as to how I could possibly extract data from these files

Comment: If you have the game it will make more sense to reverse the game and it's libraries to understand how the toc file is loaded. Understanding a file just by it's content is useless for a large number of file-formats that don't contain any structure information.

Answer (score 1):

Well the file signature seems like it's a match - `0x00 0xd1 0xce`.

"Frostbite is a game engine developed by DICE".

The python scripts here would be where I would start: https://github.com/NicknineTheEagle/Frostbite-Scripts

.. even though they don't support the latest games.